why I got error failed when installing supporting objects?
why I got this error when installing supported objects script in oracle apex ?
The DDL scrip which includes tables executed and tables installed successfully
but the script for inserting the table data not executed
this is the script its include the tables data :
begin
    --COMPANION_PERIODS: 1/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/COMPANION_PERIODS$167148
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'COMPANION_PERIODS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --DATEOFVISITS: 2/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/DATEOFVISITS$514825
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'DATEOFVISITS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --DISCHARGE_SUMMARY_MS: 1/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/DISCHARGE_SUMMARY_MS$792682
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'DISCHARGE_SUMMARY_MS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --DNR_FORM: 1/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/DNR_FORM$351489
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'DNR_FORM', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --DOCTORS_ORDERS: 8/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/DOCTORS_ORDERS$856202
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'DOCTORS_ORDERS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --DOCTORS_PROGRESS_NOTES: 21/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/DOCTORS_PROGRESS_NOTES$960823
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'DOCTORS_PROGRESS_NOTES', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --FLR_DISCHARGE_SUMMARY_GYN: 0/10000 rows exported, no file generated
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'FLR_DISCHARGE_SUMMARY_GYN', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --FLR_DISCHARGE_SUMMARY_OB: 0/10000 rows exported, no file generated
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'FLR_DISCHARGE_SUMMARY_OB', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --FLR_PATIENT_DIAGNOSIS: 5/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/FLR_PATIENT_DIAGNOSIS$348333
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'FLR_PATIENT_DIAGNOSIS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --FLR_VITALS_SIGNS: 8/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/FLR_VITALS_SIGNS$547179
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'FLR_VITALS_SIGNS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --HAJJ_COMPANIES: 13/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/HAJJ_COMPANIES$65935
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'HAJJ_COMPANIES', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --HAJJ_HOSPITALS: 18/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/HAJJ_HOSPITALS$436434
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'HAJJ_HOSPITALS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --HAJJ_HOSPITAL_MACHINES: 8/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/HAJJ_HOSPITAL_MACHINES$388
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'HAJJ_HOSPITAL_MACHINES', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --HAJJ_HOSPITAL_PROGRAMS: 18/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/HAJJ_HOSPITAL_PROGRAMS$180492
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'HAJJ_HOSPITAL_PROGRAMS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --HAJJ_PROGRAMS: 6/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/HAJJ_PROGRAMS$686721
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'HAJJ_PROGRAMS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --HAJJ_PROGRAM_TESTS: 47/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/HAJJ_PROGRAM_TESTS$143593
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'HAJJ_PROGRAM_TESTS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --HAJJ_QC_RESULTS: 0/10000 rows exported, no file generated
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'HAJJ_QC_RESULTS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --HAJJ_SAMPLES: 15/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/HAJJ_SAMPLES$810839
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'HAJJ_SAMPLES', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --HAJJ_SAMPLE_DETAILS: 3/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/HAJJ_SAMPLE_DETAILS$928721
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'HAJJ_SAMPLE_DETAILS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --HIS_USERS: 5/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/HIS_USERS$769049
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'HIS_USERS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --HOSPITAL_BEDS: 6/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/HOSPITAL_BEDS$158433
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'HOSPITAL_BEDS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --HOSPITAL_SERVICES: 703/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/HOSPITAL_SERVICES$866556
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'HOSPITAL_SERVICES', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --HOSPITAL_STAFF: 5/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/HOSPITAL_STAFF$994444
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'HOSPITAL_STAFF', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --HOSPITAL_WARDS: 3/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/HOSPITAL_WARDS$806669
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'HOSPITAL_WARDS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --ICD_CODES_DIAGNOSIS: 10000/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/ICD_CODES_DIAGNOSIS$361925
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'ICD_CODES_DIAGNOSIS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --ICD_CODES_PROCEDURES: 7359/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/ICD_CODES_PROCEDURES$165935
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'ICD_CODES_PROCEDURES', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --INP_ACCOMODATION_TRANSFERS: 0/10000 rows exported, no file generated
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'INP_ACCOMODATION_TRANSFERS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --INP_ACTUAL_INPATIENT: 7/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/INP_ACTUAL_INPATIENT$481861
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'INP_ACTUAL_INPATIENT', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --INP_ADMISSION_HISTORY: 6/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/INP_ADMISSION_HISTORY$114164
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'INP_ADMISSION_HISTORY', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --INP_ADM_CONCENT: 3/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/INP_ADM_CONCENT$842577
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'INP_ADM_CONCENT', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --INP_APPTS: 0/10000 rows exported, no file generated
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'INP_APPTS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --INP_COMPANIONS: 2/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/INP_COMPANIONS$497891
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'INP_COMPANIONS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --INP_SUPERVISSION_TRANSFERS: 6/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/INP_SUPERVISSION_TRANSFE$305659
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'INP_SUPERVISSION_TRANSFERS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --INP_TRANSFERS: 14/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/INP_TRANSFERS$65200
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'INP_TRANSFERS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --IS_ACTIVATE: 2/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/IS_ACTIVATE$65912
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'IS_ACTIVATE', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --LABS: 2/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/LABS$135971
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'LABS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --LABTESTS_HAJJ: 424/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/LABTESTS_HAJJ$245835
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'LABTESTS_HAJJ', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --LAB_ANTIBIOTICS: 79/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/LAB_ANTIBIOTICS$91705
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'LAB_ANTIBIOTICS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --LAB_CANCELLATION_REASONS: 54/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/LAB_CANCELLATION_REASONS$428040
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'LAB_CANCELLATION_REASONS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --LAB_CHARACTERISTIC: 5/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/LAB_CHARACTERISTIC$189700
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'LAB_CHARACTERISTIC', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --LAB_DEPARTMENTS: 12/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/LAB_DEPARTMENTS$625010
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'LAB_DEPARTMENTS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --LAB_MACHINES: 0/10000 rows exported, no file generated
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'LAB_MACHINES', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --LAB_ORDER_PRIORITY: 2/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/LAB_ORDER_PRIORITY$943197
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'LAB_ORDER_PRIORITY', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --LAB_ORGANISMS: 12/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/LAB_ORGANISMS$232329
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'LAB_ORGANISMS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --LAB_ORGANISMS_DETAILS: 536/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/LAB_ORGANISMS_DETAILS$664680
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'LAB_ORGANISMS_DETAILS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --LAB_ORGANISM_GROWTH: 7/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/LAB_ORGANISM_GROWTH$634700
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'LAB_ORGANISM_GROWTH', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --LAB_PATIENT_CATEGORY: 5/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/LAB_PATIENT_CATEGORY$670343
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'LAB_PATIENT_CATEGORY', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --LAB_SPECIAL_CASE: 88/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/LAB_SPECIAL_CASE$195032
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'LAB_SPECIAL_CASE', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --LAB_SAMPLE_PRIORITY: 2/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/LAB_SAMPLE_PRIORITY$336822
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'LAB_SAMPLE_PRIORITY', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --LAB_SERVICE_CONTAINER: 8/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/LAB_SERVICE_CONTAINER$19847
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'LAB_SERVICE_CONTAINER', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --LAB_SERVICE_KIND: 195/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/LAB_SERVICE_KIND$852762
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'LAB_SERVICE_KIND', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --LAB_SERVICE_SIZE: 5/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/LAB_SERVICE_SIZE$859443
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'LAB_SERVICE_SIZE', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --LAB_SERVICE_UNIT: 74/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/LAB_SERVICE_UNIT$3971
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'LAB_SERVICE_UNIT', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --MACHINES: 86/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/MACHINES$367254
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'MACHINES', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --MENUS: 69/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/MENUS$550003
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'MENUS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --MR_FILES: 8/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/MR_FILES$341068
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'MR_FILES', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --MR_FILE_DETAILS: 0/10000 rows exported, no file generated
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'MR_FILE_DETAILS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --MR_FILE_USAGE: 0/10000 rows exported, no file generated
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'MR_FILE_USAGE', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --MR_NOK: 0/10000 rows exported, no file generated
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'MR_NOK', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --MR_PATIENT_IDS: 9/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/MR_PATIENT_IDS$85841
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'MR_PATIENT_IDS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --MR_PATIENT_VISITS: 8/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/MR_PATIENT_VISITS$1467
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'MR_PATIENT_VISITS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --MR_SICK_LEAVES: 2/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/MR_SICK_LEAVES$273189
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'MR_SICK_LEAVES', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --NURSES_NOTE_TEMPLATE: 10/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/NURSES_NOTE_TEMPLATE$656276
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'NURSES_NOTE_TEMPLATE', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --NURSE_NOTES: 7/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/NURSE_NOTES$74661
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'NURSE_NOTES', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --OVR_SHEET: 0/10000 rows exported, no file generated
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'OVR_SHEET', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --PHR_ACTIVE_FORMULA: 1553/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/PHR_ACTIVE_FORMULA$563107
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'PHR_ACTIVE_FORMULA', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --PHR_FREQUENCY: 41/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/PHR_FREQUENCY$432008
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'PHR_FREQUENCY', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --PHR_RECONCILATION: 5/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/PHR_RECONCILATION$738856
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'PHR_RECONCILATION', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --PHR_RECONCILATION_MASTER: 0/10000 rows exported, no file generated
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'PHR_RECONCILATION_MASTER', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --PROGRESS_NOTES_TEMPLATES: 37/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/PROGRESS_NOTES_TEMPLATES$289782
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'PROGRESS_NOTES_TEMPLATES', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --SYS_HOSPITALS: 2/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/SYS_HOSPITALS$193181
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'SYS_HOSPITALS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --USER_GROUP: 5/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/USER_GROUP$197503
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'USER_GROUP', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --USER_GROUP_PAGE_ACCESS: 27/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/USER_GROUP_PAGE_ACCESS$859870
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'USER_GROUP_PAGE_ACCESS', p_delete_after_install => true );
    --USER_ROLE_RIGHTS: 5/10000 rows exported, APEX$DATA$PKG/USER_ROLE_RIGHTS$800038
    apex_data_install.load_supporting_object_data(p_table_name => 'USER_ROLE_RIGHTS', p_delete_after_install => true );
end;

ORA-20001: Loading table COMPANION_PERIODS failed. Errors logged in table APX$ERR$COMPANION_PERIODS$1671. This table must be dropped prior to re-running.
ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_DATA_PKG_INT", line 945
ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_DATA_PKG_API", line 50
ORA-06512: at line 3

when run install supporting objects this error appeared
the error show on first line and not inserting tables rows how to solve this error ?

"Loading table COMPANION_PERIODS failed. Errors logged in table APX$ERR$COMPANION_PERIODS$1671. This table must be dropped prior to re-running." Have you tried (a) looking at the contents of the table it lists and (b) dropping the table and re-running the script?

@MT0 I think I found the reason there is a constraint between tables there is order of executing the tables parent key table data first then FK tables data

The reason for this error was the constraints
arrange the script first I put the primary key tables then put the FK tables
then it will executed with out errors .
